# Authorize.net update and payment error in Prestashop 1.5.5

Tags: module, payment, prestashop, authorize.net

I'm on PS 1.5. I am using authorize.net payment module. Every time I process a card it says "Credit card expiration date is invalid" (In every mode test and live, test credit card and original credit card). When I look at the code there is some value for the years which are like 0,1,2,3.... when I changed the values and tested it worked. I removed a the module and installed again by downloading from the add-on store. Now the version is 1.4 and it says to update but when I update In gets updated to the same version. I switched to developer mode, tried to update and got this error.

> Notice: Undefined variable: params in /mywebsite.com/html/controllers/admin/AdminModulesController.php on line 771
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mywebsite.com/html/controllers/admin/AdminModulesController.php:771) in /mywebsite.com/html/classes/Tools.php on line 141

Please someone give some suggestion on this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. If anyone getting the same problem can try this.

What I did :

Uninstalled the old module and completely deleted that.

After deleting, searched in the payment section and found another
    module with name authorize.net (sim).

Installed that module

Now I got the latest version of the authorize.net module but that
    also didn't work

Changed the value in authorizeaim.tpl

```
<option value="{$smarty.section.date_y.index}">{'Y'|date + $smarty.section.date_y.index}</option>{/section}
```

to

```
<option value="{'y'|date + $smarty.section.date_y.index}">{'Y'|date + $smarty.section.date_y.index}</option>{/section}
```

I saw that when I was trying to make a transaction then the year value was coming like 0,1,2.... but it should be like 13,14,15....

I don't know whether it's my server not taking the value but after changing the value it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem was on the old version now this is solved in the new versions. Please refer  [prestashop github](https://github.com/PrestaShop/authorizeaim)